# Quiero hacer un CRUD relacionando estas tablas en Laravel

Tags: laravel

[image: Eso es la forma de la base]

La base de datos se llama: planilla

Categoria

php artisan make:migration **create_categoria_table**

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('categoria', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id_categoria');
        $table->decimal('costo_hora', 10, 2);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

personal

php artisan make:migration **create_personal_table**

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('personal', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id_personal');
        $table->string('paterno',50);
        $table->string('materno',50);
        $table->string('nombre',50);
        $table->unsignedInteger('categoria_id');
        $table->foreign('categoria_id')->references('id_categoria')->on('categoria')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Sueldo

php artisan make:migration **create_sueldo_table**

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('sueldo', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id_sueldo');
        $table->decimal('horas', 10, 2);
        $table->decimal('importe', 10, 2);
        $table->string('periodo');
        $table->unsignedInteger('personal_id');
        $table->foreign('personal_id')->references('id_personal')->on('personal')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema o la duda?

Comment: Hola Carlos, para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por favor lee [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y redactarla según esas sugerencias

Comment: Deberias revisar la documentacion de Laravel, la creacion de modelos y el Eloquent ORM. Eso puede ayudarte. La documentacion esta en ingles, igualmente busca al respecto en español. En la web hay mucha info. Para ayudarte en esto, es bastante complejo pues hay muchos pasos para postearlo aqui.Seria mejor que lo investigues, los temas que te cite. Saludos

Comment: El problema es que al ejecutar la migracion de las 3 tablas me sale error, y solo crea la tabla personal pero incompleto..

Comment: Primero tiene que ejecutarse la categoria, personal y luego sueldo

Answer (score 1):

si no recuerdo mal en cuanto a relaciones se refiere, deberias añadirlas en los modelos debes tener encuenta los de varios a varios y lo de uno a varios

**esta relacion va en categoria** una categoria contiene varias personas

```
public function categoria()
{
    $this->hasMany(Personal::class);
}
```

**esta en personal** una persona Tiene una categoria

```
public function personal()
{
  $this->BelongsTo(Categoria::class);
  $this->BelongsTo(Sueldo::class);
}
```

**esta en sueldo** un sueldo lo tienen varias personas

```
public function sueldo()
{
  $this->hasMany(Personal::class);
}
```

Seguramente falte algo más o haya cambiado algo, te aconsejo que mires la documentacion de [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6) lo tienes todo allí

Un saludo

Comment: Yo es que hace mucho no hago cosas con Laravel, pero tenog entendido que si quieres operar de forma relacional, debes hacer la relaciones en los Modelos, debido a que si no recuerdo mal, los Modelos son Como un Molde de como Deberian ir los datos una vez tengamos trato con ellos, cosa diferente a las migraciones, debido a que hasta donde entiendo yo, solo sirve para crear Tablas con sus respectivas Relaciones, mas no te dice como debes de operar con ellas

Comment: Lo que quiere hacer el hombre Son opreciones CRUD, con lo cual necesita los Model si o si, ahora, se necesita una respuesta mas añadiendo las operaciones CRUD no?